Django apscheduler running thrice at one time
I have a scheduler code that running every minute to send notifications using fcm... I used print statements to know where the issue is, it came to be at scheduler side I saw that it was getting called thrice. I called the backgroundscheduler in apps.py, that generally runs twice so I tried with: urls, admin, models & views.py but strangely those files were also printing twice. I can't understand why...
So I used File lock in apps.py:
import os
from django.apps import AppConfig
import threading

class MobileapisConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'MobileApis'

    _lock = threading.Lock()
    _initialized = False

    def ready(self):
        with self._lock:
            if not self._initialized:
                lock_file = '/tmp/scheduler_initialized.lock'
                if not os.path.exists(lock_file):
                    self.initialize_schedulers()
                    with open(lock_file, 'w') as f:
                        f.write('initialized')
                self._initialized = True

    def initialize_schedulers(self):
        from . import seduler
        seduler.start()
        seduler.start1()
        seduler.start2()
        seduler.start3()
        print('Schedulers started')

but that doesn't seems to work even the file is created with text... The scheduler logs are 3+ times at the same time... What's The best place that will call scheduler only one time?
